# remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com

Tags: git

I used to have a file bigger than 100M, when I push it to my repo it complained with the below error:

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin Versioni2update
Enumerating objects: 113, done.
Counting objects: 100% (113/113), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (89/89), done.
Writing objects: 100% (90/90), 5.85 MiB | 519.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 90 (delta 30), reused 2 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (30/30), completed with 9 local objects.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 251afaeaf86380e287d7a73bedd987f9
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File Code/datasets/Original DT/AnnArbor_new.csv is 116.25 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/salman-/Colonoscopy.git
 ! [remote rejected] Versioni2update -> Versioni2update (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/salman-/Colonoscopy.git'
```

As, you see, it complained about the AnnArbor_new.csv so, i ***removed this file*** and then tried to

```
git add .
git commit 
git push --set-upstream origin Versioni2update
```

But it again complained with the same error, so i tired

```
git stash
git push --set-upstream origin Versioni2update
```

So, generally it constantly complains about this big file, however i deleted it and it does not exist anymore!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Comment: You need to remove the file from previous commits. Removing it from the working tree and committing is not enough.